# Why do people say "you don't belong here" in Markarth?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim Special Edition (PC, Steam), I have committed no crimes at all in Markarth, have not yet met the Thieves Guild, and make sure to interact with people during merchants' business hours (8AM to 8PM). Yet, when I'm buying from merchants, cleansing the Hall of the Dead, or talking with anyone, I keep hearing "You don't belong here". The frequent alternate is "You need to leave". Huh? I'm doing that person a favor by investing in their business and/or buying product and they're telling me I don't belong there and I need to leave?

This isn't in relation to any quest. This is in relation to *all* interactions when I'm inside a building or room.

As a double-check, I've made sure:

- I'm disease free (by drinking a cure disease potion)
- I talked with a few guards to make sure I have no bounty.
- I haven't joined either the Stormcloak or the Imperial faction. It does get annoying after a while hearing "You don't belong here" over and over again.
- I've invested in all businesses possible and purchased goods from the merchants.
- I am not a werewolf or vampire (I haven't started the Companions quest line, and on a matter of principle, I chug cure disease potions after every encounter with vampires).

Is this another item to dump on the stack of Markarth bugs? Why am I—at this point a crime-free visitor—getting this kind of treatment?

Comment: Are you a werewolf/vampire?

Comment: @ben -- I can say with certainty that I'm not a werewolf or vampire in-game at this time. I haven't started Companions and I frequently chug cure disease after every encounter with a vampire just in case.

Comment: Are you an elf? We all know how fond the true children of Skyrim are of elves.

Comment: This behaviour can also be triggered by lockpicking and stealing, I believe. Maybe someone noticed you doing either. I've had problems with the priestess of Dibella running towards me after stealing something (pickpocketing?) and suddenly returning to her former behavioural pattern, without getting a bounty. Maybe the crime is still registered somewhere.

Comment: And you're also not wearing Daedric artefacts, perchance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like a bug involving trespass checks- perhaps it's registering you as having broken in when you enter buildings. I'd try saving, then allowing yourself to get caught actually trespassing, and see if that clears it.

Comment: That did the job. I started killing guards and got a huge bounty. I paid it off, and now I'm being treated normally.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you go into a building near closing hours the shopkeepers or whoever says it will say you don't belong here.